# Update a string using regular expressions in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-update

I have a string in my certain columns of my database:

```
<img title="\frac{3}{8}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dpi{50}&amp;space;\fn_phv&amp;space;\frac{3}{8}" alt="" />
```

Basically it contains a html code for a fraction. But now I would like to replace it with:

```
<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>
```

I know I can update the value in the database as such:

```
UPDATE table 
SET `field` = Replace(`option`, '<img title="\frac{3}{8}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dpi{50}&amp;space;\fn_phv&amp;space;\frac{3}{8}" alt="" />','<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>')
WHERE `filed` LIKE  '%<img title="\frac{3}{8}" src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dpi{50}&amp;space;\fn_phv&amp;space;\frac{3}{8}" alt="" />%'
```

However, the word "\frac{3}{8}" can change accordingly. The number in the parentheses can change and when it changes I need to change the html tag that will replace to change accordingly as well. I know I need to use regular expressions, but not sure how to do it in SQL.

Need some guidance to do it.

Comment: It would have to assess whether it is useful to apply the [replace_sections](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/replace_sections.html) function of the [common_schema](http://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/introduction.html) framework.

Answer (score 1):

Why update the table?  Why even have this stored in a table?

It seems like your application code (PHP?) could construct the string:

```
$numerator = 3;
$denominator = 8;
$img = "<img
      title="\frac{$numerator}{$denominator}"
      src=\"http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\dpi{50}&amp;
            space;\fn_phv&amp;space;\frac{$numerator}{$denominator}\"
      alt=''
      />";
```

(etc)

There is no `REGEXP_REPLACE`, except in MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, regular expressions are only supported for finding "matches", the `REGEXP` operator, which returns a boolean. There is no support for using regular expressions to return another value.

Reference: [**12.5.2 Regular Expressions** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html)

---

You said that you "*need to use regular expressions*" to do string manipulation. That means you will have to extract the column values from the database into a client application, and perform the string manipulation in the client app. (From the client, issue an UPDATE statement to assign a new value to the column, replacing the existing value.)

---

**EDIT**

If you absolutely *had* to do this in a SQL statement, then one option is to create a user defined function that could be used to perform the string manipulation.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-functions.html

It's possible someone has already coded one that does something similar to what you need. I don't want to give the impression that user-defined functions are a silver bullet; I mention it because it is an option.

Comment: Can i do it without regular expressions?